# Let user select any printer to print a report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports, printdialog

This code works well printing to default printer, but how I can do to display the Print Dialog to allow the user to select any printer?

```
var report = new ReportDocument();
report.Load(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\Reports\RouteSlip.rpt");
report.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dtData.Tables[0]);       

var prntSettings = new PrinterSettings
{
  Copies = 1,
  Collate = false,
};
report.PrintToPrinter(prntSettings, new PageSettings(), false);
```

Comment: Are you using WPF or Forms?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms225960(v=vs.90)

Comment: Hi, Im using Windows Forms.